# CSS display:table-layout issue

Tags: css, html, tablelayout

Here's my problem:

In the jsbin code [here](http://jsbin.com/avozik/25/edit). I am getting gray border of `#wrapper` hidden to the right.

However this happens only in firefox. Chrome is working fine.

Can you please let me know the fix for firefox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this example: http://jsbin.com/avupak/1/edit

Relevant CSS

```
width:100%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

`box-sizing: border-box;` computes the width including borders

Answer (score 0):

Only setting the width to 100% would also do.

```
width:100%;
```